# Upload com ASP.NET Core json vs formdata

Tags: asp.net, upload, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou usando **webapi do asp.net core**, inicialmente minhas actions estavam utilizando o atributo **[FromBody]** nos parametros, assim eu resgatava o valor json enviado pelo front-end. Agora estou implementando uma tela que tem **upload**, e tive que utilizar formdata para enviar o arquivo, e nesse momento inseri meu objeto (que antes mandava como json) no meu **formdata**. Dessa forma, precisei alterar meu back-end para que aceitasse o formdata, bastou remover o [FromBody].

Queria poder utilizar minha action, tanto passando formdata como passando um json, é possível? Como?

Answer (score 1):

Posso exemplificar com ***Exemplo Minimo***, porque, não tem tantos detalhes especifico na pergunta e sobre a pergunta da `action` ser responsável pelos dois tipos para o receber as informações e o arquivo, infelizmente não dá, o que pode ser feito é como exemplo abaixo, para um envio com `jQuery` **+** `FormData` e outra `Action` que receba `json` com `[FromBody]`.

Tenho uma classe `Elemento`:

```
public class Elemento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

e um form na página além com os dois campos, vai ser passado via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) um imagem de um `input type file` com `FormData`:

- `<form>`

  ```
  <form name="form1" id="form1">
      <input type="text" name="Id" value="1" />
      <input type="text" name="Nome" value="@Guid.NewGuid()" />
      <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" />
      <button type="button" onclick="send()">Enviar</button>
  </form>
  ```
- `ajax`

  ```
  function send() {
      var items = ($("#form1").serializeArray());
      var form = new FormData();
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      {
          form.append(items[i].name.toLocaleLowerCase(), items[i].value);
      }
      form.append('arquivo', $('#arquivo')[0].files[0]);            
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/api/Elementos",
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: form,
          success: function (message) {
              // code
          },
          error: function () {
              //code
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- `controller/action`

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Post(Elemento elemento,IFormFile arquivo)
  {
      // aqui também recupera
      var resultForm = Request?.Form;

      // aqui de forma automática
      var ele = elemento;
      var arq = arquivo; // a foto enviado            
      return Ok(new { e = elemento });
  }
  ```

---

***Código da página completa:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication2</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Index</h2>
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="Id" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="Nome" value="@Guid.NewGuid()" />
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" />
        <button type="button" onclick="send()">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function send() {
            var items = ($("#form1").serializeArray());
            var form = new FormData();
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                form.append(items[i].name.toLocaleLowerCase(), items[i].value);
                console.log(items[i].name.toLocaleLowerCase() + ':' + items[i].value);
            }
            form.append('arquivo', $('#arquivo')[0].files[0]);            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/Elementos",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form,
                success: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("There was error uploading files!");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Debug realizado para testes:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData)
- [Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)
- [2.2.6.3 Verbose JSON Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541492.aspx)
- [Updated : Upload Files In ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Form POST And JQuery Ajax)](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f1cee257-378a-42c1-9f2f-075a3aed1d98.aspx)
- [How to use FormData for ajax file upload - SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Resposta perfeita!